# is there a way to convert a string name which is ID name to "HtmlInputText" in c# asp.net?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Please help I'm creating controls dynamically that was saved in the server and looping through it and my problem is how can I pass value value from the server to the created input controls. here is my code to generate the input controls string builder and serialize it in jquery at page load.

```
public string BuildDefectStringInputGroup()
{
    var jsInputString = new StringBuilder();

    // loop to build controls
    foreach (var area in AreaList)
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConStr))
        {
            conn.Open();
            var cmd = new SqlCommand(_qryDefect, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@viewname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "SkirtCoat_layout";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@area", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = area;
            var dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            jsInputString.AppendFormat($"<div role='tabpanel' class='tab-pane' id='tab-{area.Replace(" ", string.Empty)}'>");

            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                jsInputString.AppendFormat($"<div class='col-sm-3'>" +
                                      "<div class='input-group'>" +
                                      "<span class='input-group-btn'>" +
                                      $"<button class='btn btn-danger' type='button' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='Click to decrease value' id='minus-{area.Replace(" ", string.Empty)}-{dataReader.GetValue(1).ToString().Replace(" ", string.Empty).Replace("/", string.Empty)}'>-</button>" +
                                      $"<input id='btn-{area.Replace(" ", string.Empty)}-{dataReader.GetValue(1).ToString().Replace(" ", string.Empty).Replace("/",string.Empty)}' type='button' class='btn btn-primary' value='{dataReader.GetValue(1).ToString()}'/>" +
                                      "</span>" +
                                      $"<input type='text' class='form-control' id='text-{area.Replace(" ", string.Empty)}-{dataReader.GetValue(1).ToString().Replace(" ", string.Empty).Replace("/", string.Empty)}' name='name-{area.Replace(" ", string.Empty)}-{dataReader.GetValue(1).ToString().Replace(" ", string.Empty).Replace("/", string.Empty)}' runat='server'/>" +
                                      "</div>" +
                                      "</div>");
            }

            jsInputString.AppendFormat($"</div>");
        }
    }
    return jsInputString.ToString();
}
```

and here is the code to get values from the server

```
private void GetScrapValue(string dept, string machine, string part, string area, string defectname, int prodid, HtmlInputText inputId)
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConStr))
    {
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SetScrapValue",conn))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dept", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dept;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@machine", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = machine;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@part", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = part;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@defectarea", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = area;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@defectname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = defectname;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prodid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = prodid;

            SqlParameter qtyParameter = new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "@qty",
                Value = -1,
                Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
            };
            cmd.Parameters.Add(qtyParameter);

            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            inputId.Value = cmd.Parameters["@qty"].Value.ToString(); // this is the problem
        }
    }
}
```

Finally I need to loop through all controls and set the value from the server but I can convert the string "id name" to a "htmlInputText"

```
private void SetScrapRecords()
{
    foreach (var area in AreaList)
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConStr))
        {
            conn.Open();
            var cmd = new SqlCommand(_qryDefect, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@viewname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "SkirtCoat_layout";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@area", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = area;

            var dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                var idName = Request.Form[$"text-{area.Replace(" ", string.Empty)}-{dataReader.GetValue(1).ToString().Replace(" ", string.Empty).Replace("/", string.Empty)}"]; // this where generate the ID name from all the controls generated in the page

                HtmlInputText inputName = HtmlInputText(idName); // this is my problem i dont know how to convert the "string" property to a "HtmlInputText"

                GetScrapValue("Skirt Coat", "Skirt Coat 4","81310", area, dataReader.GetValue(1).ToString(),1, ) // this is the method to grab values but I can'y convert the ID name to a htmlinput prop...

            }
        }
    }
}
```

All help will greatly appreciated thank you!!!

Comment: Why don't you use a Repeater and assign the values in the ItemDataBound event?

Comment: What do you mean by can't convert? the HtmlInputText constructor takes a string and that what  you did, so what is the error or exact problem you are getting here?

Comment: hello when I try that it gives me error:
Error CS1955 Non-invocable member 'HtmlInputText' cannot be used like a method.

Comment: and this .. 
Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText'

Comment: because the idname returns a string and the inputname should return a "htmlinputtext"?

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the line

```
HtmlInputText inputName = HtmlInputText(idName);
```

with the follow one

```
HtmlInputText inputName = new HtmlInputText(idName);
```

The operator 'new' says the compilator that you want call a constructor of a type. Now it tries to call a method with name

Comment: Thank you! that's what i thought missing!